# Uninstall Java version 11 mac

Tags: java, uninstallation

How to uninstall a specific java version from a mac?

When I execute the following command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

I see the following.

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    11.0.2, x86_64: "OpenJDK 11.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_202, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I want to uninstall just Java 11.0.2 and keep the second one.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Run this command and it will remove the JDK

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk
```

Comment: Or just toss that folder to the trash in the Finder. You will likely be prompted for an admin password.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk
```

Works for me

Comment: Close: 11.0.2 instead of 11.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Using Homebrew in the terminal did it easily for me. The following:

```
brew uninstall openjdk@11 
// use java -version to verify that it's been uninstalled.
```

worked for me. The accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: This is the correct way if you have installed jdk via homebrew. If you have directly installed the .pkg then the accepted answer is the correct way