# latest AdoptOpenJDK cannot compile Java 8 Maven project

Tags: java, macos, maven, visual-studio-code, adoptopenjdk

I had not developed Java in 10 years and needed to quickly compile a [plugin project](https://github.com/flytreeleft/nexus3-keycloak-plugin) written with Java 8 features.  I downloaded the [latest JDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) (AdoptOpenJDK 16) and installed it on my MacOS development machine.

Looking at the POM file for the project, I saw these two settings:

```
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

and [read that these settings](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) would tip the compiler that the code was written with Java 8 features and the compiled classes need to be compatible with the 1.8 JVM.

I followed [the developer instructions](https://github.com/flytreeleft/nexus3-keycloak-plugin/tree/master/develop#build-this-plugin) yet encountered errors:

Upon initial build, the following error would stop the build :

```
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.github.flytreeleft:nexus3-keycloak-plugin:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : begin 0, end 3, length 2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

[Similar people encountered the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756969/maven-enforcer-plugin-crashing-because-of-version-string-in-open-jdk) on other projects.  Ultimately I used a workaround that [was suggested to skip the maven Enforcer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108263/819019) to get past this error.

Upon rebuild, the project and would fail with about 90 compile errors in various files. The messages would say something similar to:

```
String cannot be resolved to a type
```

Which led me to [this SO questions that had a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415462/cannot-compile-maven-project) ... but no good answers.

How do I get this project to build?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to analyse what the problems in the code really are.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is install the Java 8 JDK(LTS) and build with that.

First, I removed the latest JDK from my mac [using these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55188579/819019), but in my case I had to use the appropriate directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-16.jdk
```

Second, go to:

https://adoptopenjdk.net/

and download and install the OpenJDK 8 (LTS).  This will install the correct version and point the JAVA_HOME path to the correct location.

Once this was installed, I ran the build and the plugin compiled without error.

Alternatively, you can leave both installed and point your `JAVA_HOME` to the Java 8 LTS version with the following command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_282`
```

the version string was found when I ran:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V          
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    16 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 16" 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_282 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```